# How to handle Null pointer argument to ioctl system call

Tags: pointers, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, kernel

If we pass null pointer in ioctl from user space to kernel space what will happen? how to handle this scenario?

I am expecting the solution would be using copy_to_user/copy_from_user on the pointer which performs a check on pointer to be valid or not. I want to know whether am I right.

Any further inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The null pointer can be a completely valid virtual address (user-space) as far as the kernel is concerned. Consider that the page at address zero can be `mmap()`ed with:

```
mmap(NULL, sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
```

as the superuser.

You should handle NULL pointers in the user application, where it makes sense to do so. In the kernel, you should:

- perform checks for NULL *kernel* pointers
- use `access_ok` to check the supplied pointer is actually in user space, if no `copy_to_user` is performed (`copy_to_user` calls `access_ok` anyway)

Comment: I don't think this is true. From the mmap man page: "If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the address at which to create the mapping..."

Comment: From the same man page: "If the MAP_FIXED flag is specified, and addr is 0 (NULL), then the mapped address will be 0 (NULL)."

Answer (score -1):

Yes, copy_from_user / copy_to_user is the right way to handle this. If the pointer you're given is not valid, a non-zero return will result (at which point, the kernel code should be returning EFAULT [actually usually -EFAULT]).

A null value isn't typically used as a valid pointer in either kernel mode or user mode. However, as Michael Foukrakis points out, it is possible to create an mmap region at address 0 in which case it is conceivable that a NULL pointer would be valid. In any case, copy_from_user / copy_to_user is still the right way to detect a valid address.